# Bulk record generation in aws route53 hosted zone with terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

pretty new to the Terraform world, wanna understand what's the best way to import the dns zone data in bulk to aws_route53 via terraform.

I'm essentially looking to see how to replicate `Import Zone File` functionality in `route53` via Terraform

for instance, assuming the zone data is a pretty big file generated by `dig axfr ...` like this :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> axfr zonetransfer.me @nsztm1.digi.ninja.
;; global options: +cmd
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  SOA nsztm1.digi.ninja. robin.digi.ninja. 2019100801 172800 900 1209600 3600
zonetransfer.me.    301 IN  TXT "google-site-verification=tyP28J7JAUHA9fw2sHXMgcCC0I6XBmmoVi04VlMewxA"
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  0 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  10 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  10 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  20 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  20 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  20 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  MX  20 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  A   5.196.105.14
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  NS  nsztm1.digi.ninja.
zonetransfer.me.    7200    IN  NS  nsztm2.digi.ninja.
_acme-challenge.zonetransfer.me. 301 IN TXT "6Oa05hbUJ9xSsvYy7pApQvwCUSSGgxvrbdizjePEsZI"
... (and much more)
```

It looks pretty painful/error-prone to create these resources one-by-by in a config file like:

```
//main.tf
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name = "zonetransfer.me."
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "A" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
    name = aws_route53_zone.example.name
    type = "A"
    ttl = "7200"
    records = ["5.196.105.14"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "MX" {
 //
}

// all records here
```

---

Ideally I'd like to go with something like :

```
//main.tf
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name = "zonetransfer.me."
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "all_records" {
    file = "<path_to_zone_data_file.txt>"
}
```

Any suggestions/pointers on how to handle this would be appreciated

Comment: You can't do that in Terraform. You'll have to use your first option. You could look at tools like https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer to mass import a lot of existing resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you can export it to JSON you could transform it (e.g. using `jq` or other tools) to get a list of records that you could transform using tools like [`json2hcl`](https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl) and feed the result into a terraform module that takes records as a list - like [mineiros-io/route53/aws](https://github.com/mineiros-io/terraform-aws-route53).

```
module "repository" {
  source  = "mineiros-io/route53/aws"
  version = "0.1.0"

  name = "zonetransfer.me"

  records = [
    {
      name    = "www"
      type    = "A"
      records = ["127.0.0.1"]
    },{
      ....
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

I did a migration of multiple domains with hundreds of records each from Digital Ocean to AWS that way; involving only minimal manual work. As this was a one-time task I do not have the exact conversion command lines in place anymore.

the tricky part was to group records by `type` and `name` (e.g. for MX records) using `jq`'s `group_by()` to result in the following:

```
    {
      name = ""
      type = "MX"
      records = [
        "1 aspmx.l.google.com",
        "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com",
        "10 aspmx3.googlemail.com",
        "5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com",
        "5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: In addition to this excellent solution, there is also a promising, but very new and unreviewed NodeJS tool called dns-zonefile, that claims to convert raw zone files to JSON. Caveat: I have not reviewed this for fitness for purpose or security. It could be malicious so do your own due diligence before using it! https://github.com/elgs/dns-zonefile/blob/master/README.md